# Windows Update search - remote commands not working

Tags: powershell, windows-update

Since end of October 2022 some of your windows servers (OS: 2012/R2, 2016) haven't searched for any windows updates, the status I see in the windows update GUI looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyVcS.png)

The updates are deployed via Windows Update Server (WSUS, OS: 2012 R2).

When I click on search then Windows Updates can be found, are downloaded and installed properly. This only works when I click on the search button manually. If I use remote commands like this it does NOT work (either I get an error code [OS 2016] or nothing happens [OS 2012]):

Remote commands:

1. Attempt:

```
$item = Servername

$s = New-PSSession -computername $item

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {

net stop Bits
net stop WuAuServ 
net stop CryptSvc
Remove-Item -Path C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution -Recurse
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v SusClientId /f
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v SusClientIdValidation /f
net start Bits
net start WuAuServ 
net start CryptSvc

#OS 2012/R2
wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow 

#OS 2016
usoclient StartScan

#OS 2019
usoclient StartInteractiveScan

 }
}
```

2. Attempt:

```
$item = Servername

if (schtasks /create /S $item /RU 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' /RL 'HIGHEST' /SC ONEVENT /EC Application /f /tn 'cmd' /tr 'usoclient StartScan'){
schtasks /Run /S $item /TN 'cmd'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
schtasks /Delete /S $item /TN 'cmd' /F
}
```

Results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6LTn.png)

It can't be a solution to connect via RDP to every single server and search for windows updates manually, there must be a fix to run the windows update search remotely.

Comment: The screenshot suggests that WSUS policies are in place - this sounds more like a question for [sf] than a programming question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. You are right I will shift the question to Server Fault. Thanks.